# AttributeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object has no attribute 'split'

Tags: python, list, attributeerror

I sprang up on some errors. I couldn't solve it. Basically I'm splitting my input wherever 'and' & 'or' occurs and deleting sequences having x, not x in the same sub-list. My code looks like this

```
 import string

 class list(object):

      def __init__(self, input):
          self.input = input

      def update_list(self):
          new_list = [i.split("and") for i in input.split("or")]
          print new_list

      def reduced(self):
          re_list = [m for m in new_list if not any("not" + m in new_list)]
          print re_list

 def main():
     my_input = raw_input("        ")
     print my_input
     my_list = list(my_input)
     my_list.update_list()
     my_list.reduced()

 if __name__ == '__main__':
     main()
```

errors I got:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
line 39, in <module>
   main()
line 32, in main
   my_list.update_list()
line 18, in update_list
    new_list = [i.split("and") for i in input.split("or")]
AttributeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object has no attribute 'split'
```

my input looks like this:

```
apple and berry or not apple and apple or banana and not papaya
```

desired output:

```
[['apple', 'berry'],['banana', 'not papaya']]
```

also I use Python 2.x series

I rectified the above when I replaced input with self.input in the update_list()
But I got new errors stating

```
  re_list = [m for m in new_list if not any("not" + m in new_list)]
  NameError: global name 'new_list' is not defined
```

Comment: You mean `self.input`, not `input`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The word `input` is a standard function in Python, you should avoid using it. However, in this case, within the `update_list` method, you don't mean `input` you mean `self.input`. Since you didn't specify the `self.`, it is finding the `input` function in standard python and assuming you mean that. Thus your error that a

> 'builtin_function_or_method' object has no attribute 'split'

since the builtin function `input` does not have a attribute `split`.

EDIT----

Ok, I'll give you more since you seem to still be struggling. If you want an object to retain a value from call to call, you need to use "self." to update an object's attributes.  I'm a little vague on what you want `reduced` to do, so I may have that wrong.

Note: for my own testing sanity I hard-coded the input, but you could put your `raw_input()` statement back in.

Also, stay away from names that could clobber Python built-ins, such as "list" and "input".

```
class MyList(object):
    ''' Also, classes are usually Capitalized. '''
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.raw_data = data

    def update_list(self):
        ''' I added an additional loop in order to strip away spaces. '''
        self.parsed_data = [[ j.strip() for j in i.split("and") ] for i in self.raw_data.split("or") ]
        return self.parsed_data

    def reduce_list(self):
        self.reduced_data = [m for m in self.parsed_data if m[0] != "not "+m[1] and m[1] != "not "+ m[0]]
        return self.reduced_data

def test_my_list():
    input_data = """apple and berry or not apple and apple or banana and not papaya"""
    print(input_data)
    my_list = MyList(input_data)
    print(my_list.update_list())
    print(my_list.reduce_list())

>>> test_my_list()
apple and berry or not apple and apple or banana and not papaya
[['apple', 'berry'], ['not apple', 'apple'], ['banana', 'not papaya']]
[['apple', 'berry'], ['banana', 'not papaya']]
```

Comment: I rectified that and got a new error @RobertB                                                                      `re_list = [m for m in new_list if not any("not" + m in new_list)]
NameError: global name 'new_list' is not defined`                                                       Thanks for the explanation

Comment: Do you mean to be assigning things like "new_list" as attributes of the object? In that case, you need to prefix them with "self.". I'm not really sure what to do with your comment because I don't know in what scope you are executing it. If that is code to be added to your example, go ahead and put it in the Question so I can see it in context. Also, in your question, the "def main" and "if __main__" statements are indented improperly.

Comment: Oh yeah, I indented improperly only while posting it here.

Comment: I just want to remove two literals that are **x** and  **not x** and reduce that sublist to empty list and remove them from my solution. That way my output is just `[['apple', 'berry'], ['banana', 'not papaya']]` And I just want to use the new_list I obtained from update_list()  I tried using "self" with new_list, but it didn't work

Answer (score 0):

It should be `input().split()` not `input.split()`. Add the brackets to both input and split